# attachfile vs attachfile2

Tags: packages, attachfile

I would like to attach a file to a PDF document.  I've discovered the `attachfile` and `attachfile2` packages.  How should I choose which of those to use?  Is there a general rule of thumb (e.g., "always use `attachfile2`, it is strictly better")?

I've read the documentation and the changelogs, but I'm still fuzzy on how to choose between them.

Comment: `attachfile2` is the package more up to date and extends `attachfile`, so I would say, use the newer one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Package `attachfile2` is based on `attachfile`. The latter package is loaded by the former. `attachfile2` adds features (in comparison to `attachfile` 2005/02/20 v1.2):

- New driver options `dvips`, `dvipdfmx`, `xetex`, `driverfallback`.
- New options `final` and `draft`.
- Option `scale` for scaling the annotation rectangle.
- Options `file` and `nofile` (for controlling the generation of `.atfi`).
- New option `ucfilespec` for file names with characters outside ASCII.
- Wider range of color specifications (even more, if package `xcolor` is loaded).
- Meta data about the files are collected by the Perl script `pdfatfi.pl` and populates the file parameter dictionary in the PDF file.
- Bug fixes.

See the documentation of package [`attachfile2`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/attachfile2.pdf).

I haven't checked, whether there are changes of `attachfile` since 2005 that affects `attachfile2`.