# Include matlab .m file for donwload

Tags: matlab

I was just wondering if there was a way for including a matlab.m file in latex, so you would be able to click a hyperlink in the pdf and then get a .m file ready for use.

I know you can import the .m file into lstlisting and then from there people would be able to copy paste the code. But if you wanted to skip that part, is the download/extract option then even possible on a PDF?

Of course github or another service is also a possibility, but I kind of like the idea of everything being included in one file, so if you have that file you have everything :)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182640/attachfile-vs-attachfile2/182645.